# Minor alignment issue with downvote button

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface, downvoting

When casting a downvote upon a post, I noticed that the downvote arow is misaligned between when no vote is cast and when it is downvoted. You can see below a GIMP image showing the two images next to each other to show the issue(Pardon freehand circles):

[image: screenshot edited to show misalignment]

This was tested by downvoting my own posts and getting a screenshot before it resets, but it happens on any post.

This also happens here on meta, but not on any other site that I know of.

Will something be done, or is this just too minor to deal with?

Comment: Tested, and verified on this question.

Comment: @Mahesh So, you downvoted, undownvoted, and then upvoted? :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fix will be in the next production build.